# Calendar date local notification know when recieved

Tags: ios, swift4

Here is my notification. I just want this to delete

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
         content.title = "Alarm"
         content.body = "Time to wake up!"
         content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

         let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: alarm.fireDate)
         let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
         let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: alarm.uuid, content: content, trigger: trigger)
         UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
             if let error = error{
                 print("Error scheduling local user notifications \(error.localizedDescription)  :  \(error)")
             }
         }
```

I really don't need help.

Comment: You need help or don't need help :-)

Comment: Did it solve the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to remove already delivered Notification. If my understanding is correct then you can use below API:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [alarm.uuid])
```

If you want to remove all the delivered Notifications then you can use :

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

You can find detailed api's in developer document if you are looking for something else other than this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter#1682069

Comment: If this solves your problem, do you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

- Use `removePendingNotificationRequests`

  ```
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["\(taskId)"])
  ```

***Note that in "TaskId" It's a string id of particular notification.***